# How to install "autoconf-archive" on Amazon Linux AMI EC2

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, compilation, autoconf

I'm attempting to install autoconf-archive on linux Amazon Linux AMI.
I need it in order to compile another lib for aws lambda.

```
sudo yum install autoconf-archive
```

Don't work. i get

```
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
No package autoconf-archive available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

I can not seem to manage to compile it manually nor to find an instruction on how to do so.

Thanks

UPDATE:

```
sudo yum install autoconf-archive --enablerepo=epel
```

([aws doc](https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/faqs/#epel)) did not helped..

Comment: assuming you are the same person who [opened this issue](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/796): can you post the answer as a stackoverflow answer here?

Answer (score 0):

you got a typo in 'arcive' -> you missed the 'h'.
I guess

Comment: no, that was just a typo when i was writing the question. sorry.